# Rails: accessing controller instance variables in rpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In an Rspec controller test I want to check the values of instance variables in my the controller that I am testing.

For example,

controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @things = Thing.all
  end
end
```

spec:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do 
    expect(@things).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

How do I access `@things` in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
expect(assigns(:things)).to_not be_nil
```

More likely you'll want something like:

```
let(:thing) { ... }
...
expect(assigns(:things)).to eq([thing])
```